# How to parsing the correct values from a json decoding

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular, typescript

Hii ha ve written this question because i have a json converted to a string with a function of php called json_encode()

Something like this:

```
{ "data":"2","state":"false"}
```

when the original json that im trying to encode is like this:

```
{ "data":2,"state":false}
```

(Please note that the type of the variables are different, in the original i have an int number called data and boolean called state, but when i use json_encode() every variable goes to a string..)

The problem is when i try to json.PARSE() the value from the json encode of php in angular i don´t get the correct value, every variable is a string...

For example, isntead of getting the boolean state of the variable, i get "false" or "true", and this is a problem...

There is a way to parse this avoiding this problem? basically my problem is when i parse the json in my angular project i dont get the correct type of variable..

Thanks!

Comment: Proper JSON would be: `"{\"data\":2,\"state\":false}"`; JSON does not handle single-quoted strings.

Comment: What is the exact code you used to encode the JSON ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  Assuming you mean:

input: { "data": 2, "state": false}
desired output: { "data": "2", "state": "false" }

Comment: @Hollyol is exactly like that, but when i json.parse in angular i dont get the real values, i get just a string, instead of getting false as a boolean, i get "false" as a string.

Comment: @JoshMathews Yes it is

Comment: Does the original JSON comes from JavaScript ? Or you create the object in PHP ?

Comment: @Hollyol the original JSON comes from javascript, i encode that JSON with php to convert that JSON to a string, and after i get the JSON PHP object converted to a string with json.PARSE  of javascript with angular.... as i said, the problem is that i am not getting the real type of value, every value is a string, even if i put a boolean or a number on it... I want to get the real value without having it on a string.

Comment: Can you try to pass the object to PHP as a string using `JSON.stringify()` from javascript ? I think it would do the trick

Comment: @Hollyol yes! using JSON.stringify() instead of using php solved my problem, thank you! i cannot put your answer as solved because a moderator closed my question wrongly, but you solve it thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse on an individual value to convert it into the desired type:

```js
const oldValue = JSON.parse('{"data":"2","state":"false"}')

const result = {}

Object.keys(oldValue).forEach(key => {
  result[key] = JSON.parse(oldValue[key]);
});
```

Here's the other way around:

```js
const oldValue = JSON.parse('{"data": 2,"state": false}');

const result = {}

Object.keys(oldValue).forEach(key => {
  result[key] = oldValue[key].toString();
});
```

Note: These examples assume flat objects.  You'd need to recurse through the object's tree if some of the values are objects, for example {a: {b: "c"}}.